# How to validate multiple formControls at the same time in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

**This is my main form group:**

```
this.mainForm = this.formBuilder.group({
              productType1: new FormArray([], CustomValidators.minSelectedCheckboxes()),
              productType2: new FormArray([],CustomValidators.minSelectedCheckboxes()),
              productInput : ['', Validators.required],
              productDetails : ['', Validators.required],
            });
          }
```

**and 
my custom validation function is**

```
static minSelectedCheckboxes(min: number = 1): ValidatorFn {
    const result = (formArray: FormArray): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
      const totalSelected = formArray.controls
        // get a list of checkbox values (boolean)
        .map((control) => control.value)
        // total up the number of checked checkboxes
        .reduce((prev, next) => next ? prev + next : prev, 0);
      // if the total is not greater than the minimum, return the error message
      return totalSelected >= min ? null : { required: true };
    };
    return result;
  }
```

**and i m able to get validation to get at least one checkbox.
but my requirement is to select at least one checkbox from both the FormArrays productType1 and productType2.**

that is if 5 checkbox are in productType1 
and 5 checkbox are in productType2
then my validation should go if i select checkbox from either productType1 or productType2.

Comment: Add  a custom validator to the formGroup, not formControl.

Comment: Hi Ritaj,
but if my formgroup has multiple fields other than 2 to compare, then what should be the approach?
i edited that scenario, Please find it the question. :)

Comment: Then just group them separately. `this.formBuilder.group({
             productTypes: new FormGroup({ productType1: new FormArray([], CustomValidators.minSelectedCheckboxes()),
              productType2: new FormArray([],CustomValidators.minSelectedCheckboxes())}),
              productInput : ['', Validators.required],
              productDetails : ['', Validators.required],
            });`

Answer (score 1):

**Form group init**

```
this.mainForm = this.formBuilder.group(
   {
       productType1: new FormArray([this.formBuilder.control(false)]),
       productType2: new FormArray([this.formBuilder.control(false), this.formBuilder.control(false)]),
       productInput : ['', Validators.required],
       productDetails : ['', Validators.required]
   }, 
   { 
       validator: CustomValidators.minSelectedCheckboxes(['productType1', 'productType2'])
   }
);
```

**Validator function**

```
static minSelectedCheckboxes(controlsPath: Array<string>): ValidatorFn {
    return (formGroup: FormGroup): { [key: string]: boolean} | null => {
        let valid: boolean = false;

        for (const controlPath of controlsPath) {
            const formArray: FormArray = (formGroup.get(controlPath) as FormArray); 

            formArray.controls.forEach((checkBoxControl: AbstractControl) => {
                if (checkBoxControl.value === true) {
                    selectedCheckBoxesCounter++;
                }
            });

            if (selectedCheckBoxesCounter >= 1) {
                valid = true;
                break;
            }

        return valid ? null : { minSelectedCheckboxes: true };
    };
}
```

**[STACKBLITZ Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vje3ww)**

Comment: Hey Roman, I am passing this to formarrays to display as checkboxes
productType1 = [{ id: 1, text: 'item1' },
    { id: 2, text: 'item2' },
    { id: 3, text: 'item3' },
    { id: 4, text: 'item4'  },
    { id: 5, text: 'item5'  },
    ]; and 
productType2 = [{ id: 1, text: 'item1' },
    { id: 2, text: 'item2' },
    { id: 3, text: 'item3' },
    { id: 4, text: 'item4'  },
    { id: 5, text: 'item5'  },
    ];
to get checkboxes

Comment: Can you please share some working example?
I tried to implement this way, but validations wont fire on those particular fields.

Comment: Hi, I added working stackblitz example :), see my post.

Comment: Thanks Roman, :)
in case if we dont know how many checkboxes we are getting?
then what should we do in that case.
i mean if we are getting checkboxes titles from backend then what can be done?

Comment: For the validator it doesn't matter, it will process every control of that formArray, because there is forEach cycle. You can see at `line 8`.